# Check all records in Google Chrome history

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Today I wanted to delete the history from a specific site in my Google Chrome. Filtering the history list I got more than 100 records that I wanted to remove, but I could not find a "Select All" button.
There is only a "Clean all history" button. But I do not want to clean all, I want to clean only the filtered ones.
How to check all records in Google Chrome history?

Answer (score 1):

I made some hack to accomplish this task. I can be doing a crazy thing and there can be a better way to do this, but I could not find it! So, here it goes:

1 - You can open the "Developer Tools" and go to the Console.

2 - Once in the Console, select the (history-frame/) and then enter this code:

```
var a=document.body.getElementsByTagName('input'); for (i = 0; i<a.length; i++) { a[i].checked = true; }
```

3 - Go to the history page. You will see that the "Remove selected items" will be disabled". To enable it, just unselect the first reccord and select it again.

4 - Click "Remove selected items" and have fun!